# GitHub Actions - .git folder gone when job is running as container

Tags: github, containers, github-actions

When I run a workflow job in GitHub actions as a **container**, the .git folder is missing.
There is a checkout action, of course.
This prevents me from running git commands as part of the job.
Why is that? Everything else is being mounted to the container, so why not the .git folder too?

When running the job on the runner itself, the .git folder is there as expected

Answer (score 0):

the folder is not missing its hidden. if you type whats below it should list directories and files in the .github folder

```
ls /home/runner/work/yourproject/yourproject/.github
```